# extra cell in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print start and end under execution, but I get an extra cell beside End. I use:

```
<table style="float: center;border:2px;font-size:20px;color:white;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 3;width: 25%;"> <tr><td> PC </td> <td> INSTRUCTION </td> <td> ISSUED </td> <td colspan="2"><table style="font-size:20px;color:white;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 3;width: 25%;"><tr><td>EXECUTION</td></tr></table><table style="font-size:20px;color:white;border-collapse: collapse;width: 25%;"><tr><td>START</td><td>END</td></tr></table> <td> WRITTEN </td></tr>
```

How can I remove this extra cell?
[image: how can I remove the small cell beside END?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "extra cell" is the space between the end of the cell with contents "END" and the parent cell containing your embedded tables. For your purpose, instead of embedding one table inside another you should use `rowspan` and `colspan`.

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}
table,
tr,
td {
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 3;
    color: white;
    float: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">PC</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Instructions</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Isused</td>
        <td colspan="2">Execution</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Written</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Start</td>
        <td>End</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```